# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: bitcoin

Been working with this issue when trying to run a program.

What I did:

1. Updated my system using the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Installed the necessary dependencies using the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libdb-dev \
   libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev git libssl1.0.0-dbg
   sudo apt-get install libdb-dev libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev \
   libminiupnpc-dev libminiupnpc-dev libevent-dev libcrypto++-dev libgmp3-dev
   ```
3. Extracted the tar file using the following command:

   ```
   wget gemstone.life/gemcoin-daemon-linux.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf gemcoin-daemon-linux.tar.gz
   ```
4. Installed the daemon:

   ```
   chmod +x gemstoned
   sudo mv gemstoned /usr/bin/
   ```
5. Create the config file:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/.gemstone
   nano $HOME/.gemstone/gemstone.conf
   ```
6. Pasted the following lines in yourcoin.conf:

   ```
   rpcuser= (left blank for the forum) 
   rpcpassword= (left blank for the forum) 
   rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
   listen=1
   server=1
   txindex=1
   daemon=1
   ```
7. Tried starting the node with the following command.

The error I am getting is

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have used Google, I have researched and read and read about issue and have tried uninstalling, purging, and reinstalling liboost among other things.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[@Nageek17's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094960/1095276) fix seemed to work for me. So essentially, even for newer versions you could try to run something like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1
```

and for the required libboost_* package.

Answer (score 0):

Your library probably got updated to a newer version.

Just create a link to the newer versions

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.54.0
```